# Candlestick - use tick labels with dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, matplotlib

Well, I am having a hard time understanding the conversion of dates when using the function candlestick_ohlc. I can print a chart with the dates, but in a weird format.

[image]

When I try to use the function

```
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: year 4172023 is out of range
```

Here it follows the code I am using:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
from matplotlib.dates import date2num
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
import numpy as np
import requests
import time
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

def getNow(pair):
    return requests.get('https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker').json()[pair]

def getPast(pair, period, daysBack, daysData):
    now = int(time.time())
    end = now-(24*60*60*daysBack)
    start = end-(24*60*60*daysData)
    base = 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair='
    response = requests.get('{0}{1}&start={2}&end={3}&period={4}'.format(base, pair, start, end, period))
    return response.json()

pair = "USDT_BTC"    # Use ETH pricing data on the BTC market
period = 7200       # Use 7200 second candles
daysBack = 0       # Grab data starting 0 days ago
daysData = 15       # From there collect 15 days of data

# Request data from Poloniex
data = getPast(pair, period, daysBack, daysData)

# Convert to Pandas dataframe with datetime format
data = pd.DataFrame(data)

#Convert dates do float for matplotlib
data.date = data.date.astype(float)

#Define ohlc
date, closes, highs, lows, opens, volume = data['date'], data['close'], data['high'],data['low'], data['open'], data['volume']
ohlc = [date, opens, highs, lows, closes, volume]


ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (1,0), rowspan=4, colspan=1)
#ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (1,0), rowspan=4, colspan=1, sharex=ax1)
plt.xlabel('Date')
ax2v = ax2.twinx()

#Customize the grid
ax2.grid(True, color='k', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5)  

#Rotate the axis ticklabels
for label in ax2.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(45) 

#Format the dates in the label    
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d%h'))
labels = ax2.get_xticklabels()
        
#Plot candlestick chart in the figure and set title, xlabel and ylabel
candlestick_ohlc(ax2, ohlc, colorup='#77d879', colordown='#db3f3f', width = 1)
ax2.set_title(pair+'\n')
ax2.set_xlabel('Date')
ax2.set_ylabel('Price')

plt.show()
```

.........................................................................

Comment: What date or time format is `1523894400`?

Comment: >> type(date[1])            
>> float

Comment: From the documentation:

'time must be in float days format - see date2num'

Comment: The numeric dates understood by matplotlib are *number of days since 0001-01-01 UTC, plus 1*. This means e.g. that today, 1st of may 2018 is the number `736815`. But what is `1523894400`? Which date would you expect it to correspond to?

Comment: It is unix timestamp:

timestamp 1523894400 means:
In your local time zone: Monday 16th April 2018 01:00:00 PM
UTC: Monday 16th April 2018 04:00:00 PM

Comment: Do you have an advice to better use dates in this code, @ImportanceOfBeingErnest ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to convert timestamps to numeric matplotlib dates you may e.g. use

```
data.date = date2num([dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(d) for d in data.date])
```

Next you would need to bring your data in the correct format for ohlc to understand it,

```
ohlc = list(zip(date, opens, highs, lows, closes, volume))
```

Next you need to use a valid datetime formatter, e.g.

```
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d/%m %H'))
```

Finally you need to adjust the width of your candles to something useful, e.g. `width=1./24` to make them one hour wide.